# Vanilla JavaScript - Call a function thats from the globalScope from another module

Tags: javascript, module

I work with modules. I have the following files:

main.js - its called in my index.html - file like this:

```
<script src="./js/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Gen.js - i create an instance of it within my main.js like this:

```
import {Gen} from "./classes/Gen.js";
let Gen = new Gen();
```

within my main.js, i have the following function createTopic:

main.js:

```
function createTopic() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

i want to call this createTopic() within my Gen-class, that looks like this:

```
export class Gen {
    constructor() {
    //contructor-stuff
    }
    _someMethod() {
    createTopic();
    }
}
```

Since createTopcic() is withing the "global scope", it should work, but i get an error:

"Uncaught TypeError: createTopic is not a function"

so how do i call createTopic within my Gen.js??

Comment: It's module scope, not global scope. The function would be global if you would add it to the global object `window` in this case. You can do `window.createTopic = createTopic` in the `main` and it should work, but you are making some kind of spaghetti here. Whe is `createTopic` in the `main` file?

Comment: Just move `createTopic` into the *Gen.js* module.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually attach  `createTopic` to `window` object and call it from within `Gen` class or use dependancy injection to do that.

Both examples here: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-star-mhgthi

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules